# How to adjust to the Paginator CakePHP2?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

how to adjust to the Paginator CakePHP2?

I have such a reference
http://third.loc/home/index/page:2

```
            <div class="paging">
                <?php

                echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
                echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
                echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
                ?>
            </div>
```

and how to do that was so
http://third.loc/home/page:2/

so that action could not be seen

Comment: Already running Router::connect('/home/*', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

**routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/home/page::page', array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: thank you, but now the link has changed Pagination is not working

Comment: What's the name of the controller, you requested? Can you insert the new link (after editing routes.php) here?

Comment: I used HomeController.php and index.ctp

Comment: Can you post the new link, which was created?

Comment: Please try the updated code above. I changed 'home' to 'homes'

Comment: after editing routes my link (after click on paginator) was http://third.loc/home/page:2

Comment: but the data is displayed only the first page

Comment: add a small limit to $paginate in your controller and try again.

Comment: Thank you'll understand yourself

Comment: No errors or warnings, Even the SQL limit does not change on footer

Comment: strange, please disable the cache and post the $paginate variable into a codeblock to show me.

Comment: Already running Router::connect('/home/*', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));